# Add a filter/classifier to the Python function for generating documentation for custom tags

Tags: python, documentation, python-sphinx, pdoc

I want to generate the documents for my Python project.

I know that there are a lot of useful tools that I have read about, such as pdoc and Sphinx.

One of my biggest requirements is that I want to add a tag or classifier for some functions located in different modules.

**Suppose I have three modules.**

```
ModuleA with functions: a, b, c
ModuleB with functions: d, e, f
ModuleC with functions: x, y, z
```

**Assume functions a, e, f, x are with same tag called: tag1**

```
a.py
Class ModuleA:
    def a(self):
        '''
        This is docstring
        tag: tag1
        '''
        do_somthing...

b.py
Class ModuleB:
    def e(self):
        '''
        This is docstring
        tag: tag1
        '''
        do_somthing...

    def f(self):
        '''
        This is docstring
        tag: tag1
        '''
        do_somthing...
```

How do a create a custom filter or section for tag1 on the document?

I can use the tag1 filer to list a, e, f, x functions, document, and which module they located.

Comment: Unclear. What do you mean by "custom filter or section"?

Comment: It means a filter on the left panel. With one click, I can get the tagged functions.
Like Tags on StackOverflow to filter specific categories.

Comment: Sorry, but this is still vague IMHO. Are you using Sphinx or pdoc? What exactly do you need help with? Have you tried anything at all?